# De que manera puedo acceder a una sesion en laravel sin que la contraseña este ecriptada?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tengo este pequeño inveniente, tengo una base de datos de este modo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero es poder acceder a una app en laravel con estas passwords que no están encryptadas, como puedo omitir esto en laravel?, con el usuaio que tiene password encriptada puedo acceder pero con los demas no, menciono esto porque solo lo usare en un entorno local, al momento de querer acceder con algun otro usuario me regresa este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de que laravel omita este error y puedo acceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las claves no están encriptadas, están hasheadas. En el caso del hash válido el inicio de la cadena `$2y` indica [bcrypt/blowfish 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history) el `$10` es el costo (iteraciones), lo que sigue es el salt (random para cada hash) + el hash propiamente dicho.

Para generar un hash válido que puedas insertar en la base de datos sin tener que levantar toda la app podes usar la [shell tinker](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tinker) que trae laravel, esto es básicamente un shell interactivo de php que bootstrapea laravel haciendo posible probar comandos y funciones propias de laravel desde la línea de comandos.

Suponiendo que tenemos el código de la app laravel en `/home/code/blog`, la secuencia sería algo así:

```
$ cd /home/code/blog/
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.2.11-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> echo Hash::make('123456');
$2y$10$vZLnzeQc64t374SGr44bVu8I8KUYGuOtOU7Z4ulkrnyi7yxxdaWY.
>>>
```

Si repetís el comando de hash vas a ver que el salt cambia (es random) y por lo tanto cambia el hash lo que asegura que dos usuarios con la misma clave tienen hashes diferentes.

```
>>> echo Hash::make('123456');
$2y$10$BGMqA.FxDRspxDGEDz9oyepF9GBECCHQvGp7daffdm6YkQzokKYdi
>>> echo Hash::make('123456');
$2y$10$GOVjoneAWYvkUWY/HuhQ9e7lh7ms1inlMppeC/AG09lKoAcT5Zns6
>>>
```

Para verificar una clave contra un hash se usa [`Hash::check`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing) algo así:

```
>>> if (Hash::check('123456', '$2y$10$BGMqA.FxDRspxDGEDz9oyepF9GBECCHQvGp7daffdm6YkQzokKYdi')) echo 'es válida'; else echo 'no es válida';
es válida
>>> if (Hash::check('123456asdf', '$2y$10$BGMqA.FxDRspxDGEDz9oyepF9GBECCHQvGp7daffdm6YkQzokKYdi')) echo 'es válida'; else echo 'NO es válida';
NO es válida
>>>
```

Probamos con el otro hash (misma clave salt+hash diferente):

```
>>> if (Hash::check('123456', '$2y$10$GOVjoneAWYvkUWY/HuhQ9e7lh7ms1inlMppeC/AG09lKoAcT5Zns6')) echo 'es válida'; else echo 'no es válida';
es válida
>>> if (Hash::check('123456abcd', '$2y$10$GOVjoneAWYvkUWY/HuhQ9e7lh7ms1inlMppeC/AG09lKoAcT5Zns6')) echo 'es válida'; else echo 'no es válida';
no es válida
>>>
```

Lo útil de usar el tinker es que si la app tiene configurado otro algoritmo de hash, al usar el `echo Hash::make()` te toma esa configuración, si por ejemplo editamos [`config/hashing.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/hashing.php) para que use argon:

```
$ nano config/hashing.php

//    'driver' => 'bcrypt',
      'driver' => 'argon',
```

El resultado dado desde tinker varía:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.2.11-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> echo Hash::make('123456');
$argon2i$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$VmlyQTJjcnRjUWpFbGF6cQ$n24hG2HcNyhc37dq8hR1ypt6QWsZbdd8anu6AejJPMo
>>>
```

Comment: a excelente queda mas claro, pero si necesito acceder a esta app en laravel tomanto en cuenta que los datos se ingresaron desde una app movil?

Comment: Dependerá mucho de cómo acceda la app mobile a los datos (login/auth) si es por medio de laravel  [jwt](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) / [oauth2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) no debería haber problemas (laravel se encarga de toda la mecánica), pero si la app mobile accede directamente (fat client) o a través de otro punto (api endpoint) ahí ya se pone medio ensaladesco. Idealmente navegador, app de escritorio, app mobile o [cafetera](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324) deberían todos pasar por el mismo lugar para login/auth.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendado tener contraseñas no encriptadas, pero si por alguna razón lo necesitas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
if ($user) {
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
} else {
    // login normal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el controlador RegisterController y en el método create, tienes lo siguiente:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' =>  Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
```

El facade Hash de Laravel proporciona hashing seguro de Bcrypt y Argon2 para almacenar contraseñas de usuarios. Si estás usando las clases integradas LoginController y RegisterController que están incluidas con tu aplicación de Laravel, usarán Bcrypt para registro y autenticación de forma predeterminada. Así que elimina lo siguiente:

```
 Hash::make($data['password'])
```

Por esto:

```
 $data['password'],
```